# mapping pictures to a sphere or cylinder

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, texture-mapping

i am developing an application where client can add his photos to appear on a sphere or ball or coffee cup and able to save them and give it for printing using flex. like itasveer.com site. i tried to use away3D but if the image is small it is stretched and added to sphere. i dont want it to strech instead the original image shud appear on the sphere. if it is added to cup it shud cover only the circular part it shud not add this to top and bottom. guide me how can i make it work.
-thanks in advance-madhu

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "should appear on the sphere"? Did you look at the UV mapping?

Comment: yes, thankx for ur response.we dont need to create sphere or cylinder.i shud be able to add my pic to 3D obj like cup,ball those are .png files i copy in my source(a 2D image shud be added to the 3D object). it is occupying the top, bottom and handle . it shud add the pic to only the circular part and it shud not occupy the handle. plz provide some sample code if u worked on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for making a picture into a cylinder.  I know it is in flash but I was able to port it into flex quite easily.  Essentially it takes a picture and rips it into strips and then (with a ton of math) puts them together to form a picture cylinder.  This should help with the body of the coffee cup.  There are other examples on the site for spherical photo galleries that may help (though very little) with turning a picture into a sphere.

http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/rolls/cylin.html